# How to save comparison of two SQL Server tables to Excel file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, windows-forms-designer

Well my question is related to Windows Forms, SQL Server and Excel.

I am developing an app to compare data in two tables in SQL Server, and get the results. The part up to inserting data into SQL Server tables and comparing tables is working fine, now I want to save that result of the comparison into an Excel file.

I tried many methods but have failed so far :) I am giving my function to perform SQL compare option and help and to save that result into Excel.

Thanks.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(MyConString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandText = "select Table1.Column from Table1 where Table1.Column1 not in (select Table2.Column2 from Table2 where Table2.Column2 = Table1.Column1)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
}
```

I want to save the result of this query to an Excel file

Comment: So you want a C# code to save the resault to excel file?

Comment: Yes. Exectly that

Answer (score 1):

You can save the resault to a `.CSV` file like follow:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if(checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(MyConString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader reader;

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [FileName.csv]') select Table1.Column from Table1 where Table1.Column1 not in (select Table2.Column2 from Table2 where Table2.Column2 = Table1.Column1)";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
    }
```

If you need to do that with **SSMS** you can use `Query toolbar` ,just click on `results to file` and excute your query.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Sami..
As now i got something else. and error after i used ur method . 
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

I did changed the sql Ad Hoc Permissions to 1.